# asp.net code behind show images from DB wrapped by lightbox

Tags: asp.net, database, code-behind, lightbox2

I am writing an web app in asp.net,
I have in my DB URL of my images and I want to 
display all the images from my DB wrapped with lightbox my code so far is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Lightbox/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Lightbox/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder>        </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Lightbox/js/lightbox.js"></script>  

<a rel="lightbox" id="userImageLightBox" runat="server" title="profile image">
  <img id="userImage"  runat="server"  width="150"  height="146"  alt="" src=""/>
</a>
```

so my question is:
how can i insert all my images using foreach from the code behind, that when i click on the
image the lightbox will activate

thanks

Comment: What _exactly_ are you having difficulties with? As it stands the question is too broad in scope and it is not clear what you are not understanding.

Comment: let me be clearer i want to write the code <a rel="lightbox" id="userImageLightBox" runat="server" title="profile image">
  <img id="userImage"  runat="server"  width="150"  height="146"  alt="" src=""/> from the behindcode unknown times
</a>

Comment: You have not clarified what you are having problems with. Your question includes code behind, databases, foreach and markup. Which of these are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

Use a ListView which will give you total control over the markup as well as clean HTML. Use a HttpHandler (other Q's on SO on this topic - do a search) to retrieve image from DB and serve it up.

In your ListView, use ItemTemplates to contain markup for each image. Images can be obtained by using the following syntax for each img source attribute.

```
src='ImageHandler.ashx?imageID=<%# Eval("ImageName")%>'
```