# how to bind image from database in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, .net

I have an image in a table(byte format). I want to bind this image (byte format) to an image button.I search the record and I have to display this image to this image button.Someone please help me out.Any help I would be grateful to you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you have data in `imageData` byte array

```
byte[] imageData=...;
```

You need to convert it into `base64` as follows

```
string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageData);
string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
```

An in your page you can use

```
<img src= "<%= ImageSrcBytes %>" />
```

Note that it will not work in lower end browser.

For those browsers you need to save image in local folder and then provide the url for that image.

Or you can create a handler and call that handler as image source.

Some useful links

1. [Displaying Database Images in Gridview with HttpHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573633/displaying-database-images-in-gridview-with-httphandler)

Comment: thanx shekhar i will try this and mark this as accepted if it works..m actually logging out now

Comment: Hi shekhar..m actually retrieving the records using datareader using while loop..how will I retieve that image column  from the table..byte[]image=dr[].... I mean how will i  convert the data reader object to byte format..this is my doubt..could u please help me out..i would be grateful to u